# Error 'class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0' while upgrading spring-data-mongodb from 3.3.4 to 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

Error:
cannot access org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
[ERROR]   bad class file: .m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-mongodb\4.0.0\spring-data-mongodb-4.0.0.jar(org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[ERROR]

Note: I am using OpenJDK 8 version to compile Spring boot project.

Comment: Which version of SpringBoot are you are using.  Springboot 3.x requires Java 17 or later.  See https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-and-spring-boot-versions

Comment: Also, according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/, Spring-data-mongodb 4.x requires Java 17.  So ... basically ... use OpenJDK 17 not OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Stephen C. I understood. However, I am using now <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>. I would like to upgrade to it '3.0.0'.

Comment: Did you read my second comment?  If you want to upgrade to SpringBoot 3.x or Spring-Data-MongoDB 4.x, you have to build using OpenJDK 17.   If you can't upgrade your build platform, you can't upgrade to those Spring versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue while implementing Oauth2 for security dependencies, down grading the version of the dependencies which were giving me errors helped me build my project successfully.